# Python the windows cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, ninja

I am trying to configure my own ninja binary and i get the following error. What is the cause of this?
Running on windows 7 64-bit.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via Visual Studio

Install Visual Studio (Express is fine), Python for Windows
1)In a Visual Studio command prompt: `python configure.py --bootstrap`
2)Open cmd, run vsvarsall.bat from the visual studio folder and after, call 
`python configure.py --bootstrap`